# Como recibir un componente en una prop, con ASTRO

Tags: web, icons, props

Tengo un componente en ASTRO llamado **< Card />** este mismo contiene: un icono(que es tambien un componente); un titulo,un subtitulo y un boton.

> !Cabe aclarar que me refiero a  un componente de astro , es decir no
> estoy usando REACT!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El punto es que el codigo de las dos tarjetas se repite, por lo que entiendo es una buena idea convertirlas en un componente en vez de repetir todo el codigo, pero lo que deberia ser diferente en cada tarjeta seria: "*el icono","el titulo", "el subtitulo".*
Como se puede observar en la imagen, los textos no son problema.
pero como logro que cada  **< Card/>** reciba tambien como prop un componente que contenga el icono necesario?

Comment: Tengo el mismo dilema. Estaré atento.

Answer (score 1):

Veo que ha pasado tiempo desde que hiciste tu pregunta, vengo aprendiendo Astro hace poco y tengo que decir que es muy potente.

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, en ves de querer recibir un componente podrías hacer lo siguiente, te mostrare 2 ejemplos.

por lo que veo tus botones son iguales, entonces no veo la necesidad de pasar el mismo botón cada ves.

ejemplo:

```
 <div class='...'> 
    <img src={`...path/{img}`} class='...'/>
    <h3 class='...'>{title}</h3>
    <p class='...'>{subtitle}</p>
     <button class='...'>
        <img src={`...path/{icon}`} class='...'/>
     </button>
 </div>
```

en caso de que el botón sea un componente con diseños que pueden cambiar podrías pasar tu componente exactamente igual, ejemplo:

```
    <div class='...'> 
        <img src={`...path/{img}`} class='...'/>
        <h3 class='...'>{title}</h3>
        <p class='...'>{subtitle}</p>
        <CustomButton icon={`...path/{img}`} type='default' />
     </div>
```